# Java Bookstore program

Tags: java

I am writing a bookstore program for homework. The program gives the user 6 different options for them to select from. Currently, the one I am working on is option 1. Option 1 is to add more books to the stock. When the user selects option 1, it asks the user to enter the book title, it then checks if the books is already in stock. The problem that I am having is checking to see if the book title that the user enters in is already in stock. I have a function called inStock, but I am unsure of how to call this function. Right now the code does not compile because I am receiving an error on the line that says `if (bt == myBkStore.inStock(title, y))` because of incompatible types. But I am not sure of how to call the inStock() function. This is my coding so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyBookstore {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Bookstore myBkStore = new Bookstore();


    int y = 0;
    int user_choice = 2;
    boolean quit = false;

    do {
        //display menu to user
        //ask user for his choice and validate it (make sure it is between 1 and 6)
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1) Add a book to the stock");
        System.out.println("2) Sell a book in stock");
        System.out.println("3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)");
        System.out.println("4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)");
        System.out.println("5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore");
        System.out.println("6) Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter choice [1-6]: ");
        user_choice = s.nextInt();
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Enter a book title");


                    String bt = s.next();           //stores title of book user enters in

                    if (myBkStore.inStock(title, y))
                    {
                        System.out.println("How many more to add to the stock");
                        y = s.nextInt();
                        myBkStore.addBookQuantity(bt, y);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter the amount of pages of the book: ");
                        int pages = s.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter the price of the book: ");
                        double price = s.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter the quantity to add: ");
                        int quant = s.nextInt();
                        //myBkStore.Book(bt, pages, price, quant);
                        myBkStore.addNewBook(book);
                    } 


                    break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Enter book title to buy: ");
                    String bookT = s.next();
                    myBkStore.sellBook(title, y);
                    break;
            case 3: myBkStore.listTitles();
                    break;
            case 4: myBkStore.listBooks();
                    break;
            case 5: myBkStore.getIncome();
                    break;
            case 6: System.out.println("Thanks for coming");
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            default: System.out.println("\nInvalid Choice");
        }
}
while (!quit);
}

static class Bookstore {
private Book[] books; // all the books in this bookstore
private int totalBooks; // the number of books in this bookstore
    private double grossIncome; //the gross income of the bookstore (will be incremented when books are sold)

// Constructor: A new Bank object initially doesn’t contain any accounts.
public Bookstore() {
    books = new Book[100];
    totalBooks = 0;
    grossIncome = 0;
    }

// Creates a new bank account using the customer name and the opening balance given as parameters
// and returns the account number of this new account. It also adds this account into the account list
// of the Bank calling object.
public void addNewBook(Book b) {
    if(totalBooks < books.length) {
        books[totalBooks] = b;
        totalBooks++;

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\nSorry, cannot add book to stock.");
    }


}


public void addBookQuantity(String title, int quantity) {
    for (int i =0; i<totalBooks; i++) {
        if (title == books[i].getTitle()  ) {
            books[i].addQuantity(quantity);
            System.out.println("Quantity added successfully");
            return;
        }
    }

    /*int i;

    for (i = 0; i < totalbooks; i++)
    {
        if((books[i].getTitle()).equals(title))
        {
            books[i].addQuantity(quantity);
            return;
        }
    }*/


}

public boolean inStock (String title, int quantity) {
    for (int i =0; i<totalBooks; i++) {
            if (title.equals(books[i].getTitle())) {
                if (quantity <= books[i].getQuantity()) {return true;}
                else {return false;}
            }
        }
    return false;

}

public boolean sellBook(String title, int quantity){
    int i;

        boolean sellflag=false;

        // Checks to see if the books are in stock.

        boolean retval = inStock(title, quantity);

        // If so, completes the sale.

        if (retval) {

          for (i=0; i<totalBooks && !sellflag; i++) {

            if (title.equals(books[i].getTitle())) {

              books[i].subtractQuantity(quantity);

              grossIncome += (books[i].getPrice()) * quantity;

              sellflag = true;

            }

          } // for

        } // if

        return retval;

      } // sellBook






public void listTitles()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(books[i].getTitle());
    }

}

public void listBooks()
{
    int i;

    System.out.println("\nList of Books\n======");
    for (i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(books[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public double getIncome()
{
    return grossIncome;
}





}





  static class Book{

       private String title;
       private int numOfPages;
       private double price;
       private int quantity;
       private Book book;

       public String toString(){
           return "Title: " + title + "\nNumber of pages: " + numOfPages + "\nPrice:" + price +"\nQuantity: " + quantity + "\n";


       }


       public Book book(String thetitle, int pages, double cost, int num){
         /*title = thetitle;
         numOfPages = pages;
         price = cost;
         quantity = num;*/
         return book;

       }

       public String getTitle(){
         return title;
       }

       public double getPrice(){
         return price;
       }

       public int getQuantity(){
         return quantity;
       }

       public void addQuantity(int amount){
            quantity = quantity + amount;

    }
    public void subtractQuantity(int amount)
    {
          System.out.println("Amount to buy");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        quantity = s.nextInt();
        quantity = quantity - amount;   
    }

}//end of class
}
```

Comment: By the way, the if statement in your addBookQuatity() method won't work since you're using "==" to compare Strings. You should use equals() as you have done in other instances.

Comment: ok, so that line of code should read `if(title.equals(books[i].getTitle() ) )` is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bt is a String:

```
String bt = s.next();
```

but inStock() returns a boolean:

```
 public boolean inStock(...)
```

so when you call:

```
       if (bt == myBkStore.inStock(title, y))
```

you are saying "if this string (bt) is equal to this boolean (returned by inStock)"...

the types here are incompatible, hence the exception

EDIT: To simply check whether the inStock returns true or false, you can simply say:

```
   if (myBkStore.inStock(title, y))
        // do stuff you want to do if the inStock() method returns true
   else 
        //do stuff you want to do if the inStock() method returns false
```

Note: `(myBkStore.inStock(bt, y))` is a shorthand way of saying

```
 if (myBkStore.instock(title, y) == true)
```

Comment: yes, i understood that error. For some reason I could not figure out how to call my inStock() to check that book is in stock

Comment: thanks very much drewmore. now does not like my calling of my inStock() in the case statement, and also receiving error in the function itself on the line saying `if ((books[i].getTitle()).equals(title)) {`

Comment: @bobGlenn please edit your question or post a new one with your new problems, including the updated code and the actual exceptions thrown ("does not like" does not give us anything to work with). PS - why would you accept an answer before your question is fully answered?

Comment: the code compiles, but it is the console window saying that there is an error. It only gives me the line where the error is occurring, and not an actual error message

Comment: its ok, I was able to figure that out. I do have another problem. It is involving my subtractQuantity(). It compiles and somewhat works, but when I select option 4, the quantity that I chose to buy is now the new quantity in stock. rather than taking the current quantity and subtracting from the amount the user wants to buy

Comment: That's because you call `quantity = s.nextInt();`. It seems like what you want to be calling is `amount = s.nextInt();` and `quantity = quantity-amount`.

Comment: Oh man. Such a silly mistake. Hehe. Thanks. This is my last problem. Option 5 to print out the gross Income. I am unable to get any type of information to be displayed when I select option 5. It just gives me the menu options again

Comment: Your `getIncome()` method returns a double, but it doesn't actually print it to the screen. You need to call `System.out.println(myBkStore.getIncome())` in your switch statement, or add a `println` statement to the getIncome() method.

Comment: Ok, I am able to get some type of output now. But my answer comes up as 0.0.

Comment: Well, you define `grossIncome` as 0 in your constructor. Then, the only time you do anything to it is in the `sellBook()` method. So, if you call `getIncome()` without ever calling `sellBook()`, then `grossIncome` is still going to be 0. Try calling `sellBook()` and then calling `grossIncome()`, and you'll see something other than 0

Comment: calling sellBook() in the grossIncome() ? is that what you mean?

Comment: No, when you're actually running the program, select option 2 and go through that and then select option 5

Comment: Then your `sellBook()` method is not completing properly. You should add some diagnostic println() statements in that method to see what it's doing. Your issue might be that you're passing `title` to the method rather than passing the String inputted by the user (in your switch). I don't even see where you're initializing `title`??

Comment: actually, i found the problem. the problem was in my case statement. I had this line of code for my case 2 statement where I was selling a book. `System.out.println("Enter book title to buy: ");
                    String bookT = s.next();
                    myBkStore.sellBook(bookT, y);` 
Here I am calling my sellBook() passing only bookT, but I realized that y was still 0. So i added in a value that the user enters in to be stored into y. Now it works!! Thanks for all of your help!! Really appreciate you help

Answer (score 2):

bt is a String. The return type of your inStock method is a boolean. You need to store inStock's return value to a boolean. And then use whatever is returned from your inStock method in your if statement. For example:

```
if (myBkStore.inStock(title, y)) { // this statement basically means if (myBkStore.inStock(title, y) == true)
    // then do stuff
}

OR

if (!myBkStore.inStock(title, y)) { // this statement basically means if (myBkStore.inStock(title, y) == false)
    // then do stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for. not sure why i was unable to think of that. hehe. but it does not seem like to my inStock().

Comment: @bobGlenn Is the inStock() method not working or are you getting more errors?

Comment: i get an error in the case statement in the if statement. it does not produce the true part, if the book is already in stock, prompting the user to input how many more to add in stock. also receiving an error on this line in the inStock() function `if ((books[i].getTitle()).equals(title))` the code compiles, but when i test to check if the book is in stock, i get the error messages on the console window

Comment: @bobGlenn Okay I tried to look at your code and go through it but it seems like there are a lot of things wrong. I would suggest breaking the problem down into smaller pieces and then building the program up from there. One thing that you should try to do for all of your programs is add one functionality at a time and then test and make sure that runs perfectly before moving on to the next one. If, after breaking your program down, you still can't figure it out then come back to this site and ask specific questions like you did here.

Answer (score 0):

Jus try to replace

```
if (bt == myBkStore.inStock(title, y))
```

with:

```
if (myBkStore.inStock(bt, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove bt == from your code. It should work

```
if (myBkStore.inStock(title, y))
{
    System.out.println("How many more to add to the stock");
    y = s.nextInt();
    myBkStore.addBookQuantity(bt, y);
}
```