# Questions about calling a constructor and defining the variables in Java (Homework)

Tags: java

To be clear, this is an active homework assignment. I just need some guidance.

I am creating a bookstore program in Java that, in revision 1, only has to return information about one specific book when it runs. I must use two classes, and call the info in the secondary class inside the main method to output.

I think I created the constructor correctly inside the Book class, but what's the best way to A) define those variables and B) call the info inside the Bookstore class to output? I just need some guidance here, as I'm kinda stuck. Eclipse is asking me to re-define the int and double variables as a String, but they are going to be numbers...is there something in my syntax that is causing it to do that?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Import Scanner

/** Main Class */
public class Bookstore {

/** Secondary Class */
private class Book {


    /** Declare Variables */
    private int isbn;
    private String bookTitle;
    private String authorName;
    private int yearPublished;
    private String publisherName;
    private double bookPrice;

    /** Constructor */
Book (int isbn, String bookTitle, String authorName, int yearPublished, String publisherName, double bookPrice) {
        setIsbn(isbn);
        setBookTitle(bookTitle);
        setAuthorName(authorName);
        setYearPublished(yearPublished);
        setPublisherName(publisherName);
        setBookPrice(bookPrice);    
    }

    /**
     * @return the isbn
     */
    public void getIsbn(int isbn) {
        return isbn;
    }

    /**
     * @param isbn the isbn to set
     */
    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bookTitle
     */
    public void getBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
        return bookTitle;
    }

    /**
     * @param bookTitle the bookTitle to set
     */
    public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    }

    /**
     * @return the authorName
     */
    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }

    /**
     * @param authorName the authorName to set
     */
    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the yearPublished
     */
    public int getYearPublished() {
        return yearPublished;
    }

    /**
     * @param yearPublished the yearPublished to set
     */
    public void setYearPublished(int yearPublished) {
        this.yearPublished = yearPublished;
    }

    /**
     * @return the publisherName
     */
    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }

    /**
     * @param publisherName the publisherName to set
     */
    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bookPrice
     */
    public double getBookPrice() {
        return bookPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @param bookPrice the bookPrice to set
     */
    public void setBookPrice(double bookPrice) {
        this.bookPrice = bookPrice;
    }

} // End Book Class

/** Main Method */
public static void main(String[] args) {



} // End Main Method

} // End Bookstore Class
```

That's where I'm at. Again, I'm stuck on how to define the variables properly, and then call the data for output in the Bookstore method. I know how to print it to the screen, it's just getting it there that is perplexing me. Do I create another Book object inside the Bookstore class?

I appreciate any help that's available.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I am just curious to ask why this -->private class Book?

Comment: I can't see a real question there, and asking for "best" way is not really constructive.There are plenty of ways

Comment: I thought my questions were clear, my apologies.

Comment: Some of your getters don't have a return type, but are trying to return values. For example, getIsnb doesn't need a parameter value but should retin int

Comment: I think I created the constructor correctly inside the Book class, but what's the best way to A) define those variables and B) call the info inside the Bookstore class to output? I just need some guidance here, as I'm kinda stuck. Eclipse is asking me to re-define the int and double variables as a String, but they are going to be numbers...is there something in my syntax that is causing it to do that?

Comment: @KickButtowski I am tasked to use two classes in this assignment. The main Bookstore class, and the Book class, which will define the variables.

Comment: Implement a toString() method in your Book class to return a string containing information on the Book. Implement an array of books inside your Bookstore. In your main method create a few book objects and add it to the Bookstore. Loop through the Books in the bookstore and print them to the console.

Comment: @DanZaleski can you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913863/java-why-can-we-define-a-top-level-class-as-private?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914366/java-bookstore-program

Comment: @KickButtowski I was under the impression that all nested classes had to be private, and that you can't have two public classes in the same file. The document you linked would seem to confirm that. I think I have that part set-up correctly, no?

Comment: @DanZaleski I am just learning like you :) I did not see that, so I was curios to ask cuz I always make different classes for my projects.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Eclips is erring there, telling me it should be a String, but I want it to stay an int. Is it my syntax in that getter that's going that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with...

```
private class Book {
```

I would say declaring an inner class as `private` might not be the best choice, as you not be able to use beyond the scope of `BookStore`, but that's a choice you need to make...

This...

```
/**
 * @return the isbn
 */
public void getIsbn(int isbn) {
    return isbn;
}
```

is wrong on a number of accounts.  First, it is declared as `void`, meaning that the method won't return anything, but then you use `return isbn` within the method.  It should be declared as returning an `int`.

Next, you pass `isbn` as a parameter to the method, but immediately return the same value, this isn't really what you want to do, you want to return the value of `isbn` defined by `Book`, for example...

```
/**
 * @return the isbn
 */
public int getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}
```

The same thing goes for `getBookTitle`.

In some languages they pass parameters by reference, meaning you can actually alter the value in the method/function and that will be reflected in the callers context. Java doesn't do this (more accurately, you can't reassign the value within the method and have it reflected in the caller).  This is tripping point for many developers.

Basically, this means you can't do something like...

```
public void getBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
    bookTitle = this.bookTitle;
}
```

As the value of the parameter will the same in the callers context after the method call as it was before it.  You have to "get" the value from the class.

An interesting side effect though, is you can change the properties of objects passed to a method, if they supply mutable functionality...

Comment: So the correct method for isbn would be: 'code'public int getIsbn(int isbn) {
   return isbn;
  }

  /**
   * @param isbn the isbn to set
   */
  public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
   this.isbn = isbn;
  } 'code'